# How to rename tab's text on double click in JavaFX 2?

Tags: tabs, javafx-2

I have a simple code to add tab(s) to a tabPane

```
@FXML
private void addNewWorkspaceTab(ActionEvent event) {

    Tab workspaceTab = new Tab();
    workspaceTab.setText("New Workspace");
    tabpaneWorkspace.getTabs().addAll(workspaceTab);
    tabpaneWorkspace.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB);

}
```

By double left mouse click on a tab I would like to rename (by typing a new text) the selected tab: how can I do this?

Comment: what exactly is the problem, the onmouseclicked with clickcount or the renaming. Should the textfield be inline(Inline-Editing) or just a simple TextField somewhere else?

Comment: I would like to change text: now the tab has "New Workspace" as text, I would like to set this text as editable in order to type a new String

Comment: because tab has no onclickhandler i think the best way is to set the `tab.setGraphic(...);` to a button and implement it there(MouseEvent has an clickCount)..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for my question:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

/**
*
* @author utente
*/
public class TabSetText {

public Tab createEditableTab(String text) {  
final Label label = new Label(text);  
final Tab tab = new Tab();  
tab.setGraphic(label);  
final TextField textField = new TextField();  
label.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {  
  @Override  
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {  
    if (event.getClickCount()==2) {  
      textField.setText(label.getText());  
      tab.setGraphic(textField);  
      textField.selectAll();  
      textField.requestFocus();  
    }  
  }  
}); 


textField.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {  
  @Override  
  public void handle(ActionEvent event) {  
    label.setText(textField.getText());  
    tab.setGraphic(label);  
  }  
});


textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {  
  @Override  
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,  
      Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {  
    if (! newValue) {  
      label.setText(textField.getText());  
      tab.setGraphic(label);            
    }  
  }  
});  
return tab ;  
}  

}
```

Comment: Here's a slightly modified version that accepts a StringProperty, so that the name can be bound to something else: https://github.com/sirolf2009/caesar/blob/35006dc64da24a3ac37136c6d9c555df843ac3b8/src/main/java/com/sirolf2009/caesar/component/RenameableTab.java