# Changing Header Of JFXTabPane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, material-design, jfoenix

I am working on a `JavaFX` project and I am creating an UI based on Google's Material Design patterns. I use a library that includes a lot of components based on this design, named `JFoenix`.

Basically I have a `JFXTabPane` with different tabs, and in one of them I want to make something to Search on a `TreeTableView`, and I got as idea to replace the `TabPane`'s header (where the tabs display) with the Search bar.

I've been looking this up on Google and haven't found anything. Any ideas?

Comment: As an entry point you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170305/how-to-rename-tabs-text-on-double-click-in-javafx-2).

Comment: @Marcus That's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I think that replacing the header with a search field is confusing for the user because the tabs are meant to be pressed and switch the current content. If you show more of your GUI design perhaps someone can come up with a better solution. In any case, if you want to do it anyway you'd have to change the skin in `TabPaneSkin`.